# Open Source Quizzes Self-Hosted

Tags: open-source, survey

I'm looking for a web-based Open Source QUizzes software for take multiple choice examinations.

I don't want to install something like Moodle. I need only quizzes:

- Make question using web gui
- Get the results of every student
- Notify to students their qualifications by mail

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in case of interest I have solved similar by using drupal with its [quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module.

- You can create multiple-choice questions via the GUI or even import from text file. You also have the option of other question types
- The admin or any user with right permissions can see results of all students.
- Students can be notified by email. You can also show them the results immediately after the test, depending on configuration settings for the quiz.

The module has many more features, but you can use only what is required.